# Should I use global variables?

Tags: c++, singleton, g++, global

I have been reading about global variables and how bad they are but I am stuck in one place due to that. I am going to be very specific about if I should use global variables in this scenario.

I am working on a game engine. And my engine consists of lots of managers. Managers do certain tasks - they store resources, load them, update them etc.

I have made all my managers a singleton because so many classes and functions needs access to them. I was thinking of removing the singleton but I don't know how i can not have it and get access to these managers.

Here is an example of what I am trying to tell (im bad at english, sorry):

Singleton.h

```
template<class T> class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton( const Singleton& );
    const Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& );

protected:
    Singleton() { instance = static_cast<T*>(this); }
    virtual ~Singleton() {}

protected:
    static T * instance;

public:
    static T &Instance() {
        return *instance;
    }

};
```

ScriptManager.h

```
class ScriptManager : public Singleton<ScriptManager> {
public:
    virtual void runLine(const String &line)=0;
    virtual void runFile(const String &file)=0;
};
```

PythonScriptManager.cpp

```
class PythonScriptManager : public ScriptManager {
public:
    PythonScriptManager() { Py_Initialize(); }
    ~PythonScriptManager() { Py_Finalize(); }

    void runFile(const String &file) {
        FILE * fp = fopen(file.c_str(), "r");
        PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, file.c_str());
        fclose(fp);
        fp=0;
    }

    void runLine(const String &line) {
        PyRun_SimpleString(line.c_str());   
    }

};
```

Entity ScriptComponent

```
#include <CoreIncludes.h>
#include <ScriptManager.h>
#include <ScriptComponent.h>

void update() {

    ScriptManager::Instance().runFile("test_script.script");
    //i know its not a good idea to open the stream on every frame but thats not the main concern right now.
}
```

Application

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv) {
    Application * app = new Application(argc, argv);
    ScriptManager * script_manager = new PythonScriptManager;
    //all other managers

    return app->run();
}
```

As you see I am not even including the files above in my ScriptComponent.cpp file which wins me some compilation time. How can I get that kind of a result without globals which will make it easy to integrate as this one. The singleton is not thread safe but adding threads won't take a long time.

I hope I could explain the problem.

Thanks in advance,
Gasim Gasimzada

Comment: There's no mystery. The way to avoid globals is to not have them. If function A needs to access object B, and B isn't global, then B has t obe passed as an argument to A. And that's how you do it if you don't have globals. Pass the necessary objects as function (or constructor) arguments.

Comment: Since I cannot comment on your posts im going to comment here. @jalf i really understand that globals are bad and an alternative and robust solution is to pass the values to the arguments of functions or c'tors. But I am getting two big problems in that case? From where am I getting those managers (they are actually just wrappers to make coding easier)? @Dave said to make the 'executive' object (lets call it Engine) which stores all these objects and pass the references to the function or c'tor. But how am I doing it? I want to make it easier and cleaner.

Comment: Actually nevermind. I have found a way :) The only reason I wanted to use singletons is because I will have to have very little dependency in each source file but now I have found a way :) thanks guys for all your help! Now getting back to work.

Comment: you just create the objects wherever it makes sense. For the sake of simplicitly, you could create them in the main function, and then pass them to wherever they're needed. (although, again, "manager" objects should make your warning lights go off. "wrappers to make coding easier" are fine, but it shpould always be clear what they wrap, and what their responsibilities are. "managers" typically fail that. It's possible that all that's needed is a more telling name, rather than a complete redesign of the class.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I won't say you should *never* use globals, but:

- *Never* use singletons. [Here](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/) is why. They're horrible, and they're much worse than plain old globals.
- "Manager" classes are bad. What do they "manage"? How do they "manage" it? "Manager" classes need to be broken up into something that you can describe. Once you've figured out what it means to "manage" an object, you can define one or more object with better-defined responsibilities.
- When you use globals, don't make them mutable. A write-only global can be acceptable (consider a logger. You write to it, but its state never ever affects the application), and read-only globals can be ok too (consider various constants that are never changed, but which you frequently need to read from). Where globals become harmful is when they have mutable state: when you both read to, and write from, them.

And finally, the very very simple alternative:
Just pass dependencies as arguments. If an object needs something in order to function, pass it that "something" in its constructor. If a function needs something in order to operate, pass it that "something" as an argument.

This might *sound* like a lot of work, but it isn't. When your design is cluttered with globals and singletons, you get a big huge spaghetti architecture where everything depends on everything else. Because the dependencies are not explicitly visible, you get sloppy, and rather than *thinking* about what the best way to connect two components is, you just make them communicate through one or more globals. Once you have to think about which dependencies to explicitly pass around, most of them turn out to be unnecessary, and your design becomes much cleaner, more readable and maintainable, and much much easier to reason about. And your number of dependencies will drop dramatically, so that you only actually need to pass an extra argument or two to a small number of objects or functions.

Comment: However, std::cout is a global non-const object. I think all depends on the behaviour or nature of that global object, or context of your program. Does that object has a very tiny interface or has a very packed behaviour? Ok, perhaps a global is not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 4):

How about removing the `ScriptManager` base class and use static methods in the specialization classes? It looks like there is no state involved with any `ScriptManagers`, and no real heritage other than the purely virtual functions.

I could not figure out from your code samples if you actually use polymorphism here. If not, static member functions look OK to me.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have actually changed my code to something like this. and got rid of all the singletons.

Answer (score 2):

Do not ever use global variables. If you need an object of a type, then you pass it in, by reference if necessary.

Comment: This an overly-simplictic statement - for example it may be clearer to have a global 'logger' object which different methods can call to log debugging information instead of passing a reference to the logger object to _every_ other object in the application.

Comment: -1 for preaching a good guideline as absolute imperative and giving absolutely zero reasoning for it. I'm not saying globals are good, or even acceptable in most cases - *because* I agree that globals are bad, I want that guideline to be presented and backed up better.

Comment: It may be overly simplistic, but advice always is. Speed limits on roads are overly simplistic too, because providing a full and accurate account of when and how it is safe to drive exactly how fast is just unrealistic. The point in advice is to provide a simple rule that you can use as a guideline. It can never take *everything* into account, but as a rule of thumb, "do not use global variables" is perfectly reasonable. ANd @delnan: downvoting an answer you agree with, just because you're not satisfied with the rationale, is pretty harsh. :)

Comment: @jalf: I agree that globals should be avoided. I do not agree that the must not ever be used. And I think that such a statement plus a hint on a "solution" that doesn't imply (much) improvement (if you simply apply it without changing the design, you still share just as much state between unrelated parts of the program, which is one - IMHO the main - reason globals are bad) is a useful (mind you, that's exactly what it says on the +1/-1 arrows) answer.

Comment: The OP clearly is not a C++ genius and I'm not going to complicate his life by giving the breakdown. He needs simple, clear advice, and this is it.

Comment: +1 @ dead.  The hardest part of using SO, is correctly inferring the experience level of the questioner and answering the question at a similar level.