# Image first loaded, then it isn't? (XNA)

Tags: xna, c#

I am very confused at the Moment.

I have the following Class: (Just a part of the class):

```
 public class GUIWindow
{
    #region Static Fields
    //The standard image for windows.
    public static IngameImage StandardBackgroundImage;
    #endregion
}
```

IngameImage is just one of my own classes, but actually it contains a Texture2D (and some other things).
In another class I load a list of GUIButtons by deserializing a XML file.

```
public static GUI Initializazion(string pXMLPath, ContentManager pConMan)
    {
        GUI myGUI = pConMan.Load<GUI>(pXMLPath);
        GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage = new   
        IngameImage(pConMan.Load<Texture2D>(myGUI.WindowStandardBackgroundImagePath),
                 Vector2.Zero, 1024, 600, 1, 0, Color.White, 1.0f,
                 true, false, false);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Image loaded? " +  
                                (GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip != null));
        myGUI.Windows = pConMan.Load<List<GUIWindow>>(myGUI.GUIFormatXMLPath);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Windows loaded");

        return myGUI;
    }
```

Here this line: System.Console.WriteLine("Image loaded? " +
                                    (GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip != null));
Prints "true".
To load the GUIWindows I need an "empty" constructor, which looks like that:

```
public GUIWindow()
    {
        Name = "";
        Buttons = new List<Button>();
        ImagePath = "";
        System.Console.WriteLine("Image loaded? (In win) " + 
                                (GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip != null));
        //Image = new IngameImage(StandardBackgroundImage);
        //System.Console.WriteLine(
        //Image.IsActive = false;
        SelectedButton = null;
        IsActive = false;
    }
```

As you can see, I commented lines out in the constructor. Because: Otherwise this would crash.
Here the line System.Console.WriteLine("Image loaded? (In win) " + 
                                    (GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip != null));
Doesn't print anything, it just crashes with the following errormessage:

> Building content threw NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an object instance.

Why does this happen?
Before the program wants to load the List, it prints "true". But in the constructor, so in the loading of the list it prints "false".
Can anybody please tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Use your debugger. NullReferenceException means you're trying to do something with a variable that's set to null.

Comment: Are you using the [game state management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) code from MSDN?

Comment: The fact that the exception is thrown while building content and not, apparently, when running the app should be a clue. Why is this code running during a content build? What are you trying to compile as content that could be causing it to run?

Comment: Migrating to Stack Overflow at M0rgenstern's request, in hopes that someone can shed more light on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess at the NullReferenceException is that `GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage` is null, so it throws this exception when you try to access `GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip`.

Are you familiar with the Visual Studio debugger? If not, you should be. I'd set some breakpoints and step through any code that reads or writes `StandardBackgroundImage`.

Really, though, your organization could be improved. Why is `StandardBackgroundImage` a static field of the `GUIWindow` class? It should be a field of the class which loads it - wherever the `Initialization` method is. Then pass it into the constructor of GUIWindow.

You are treating the `StandardBackgroundImage` field like a global, and thus are feeling the effects of that decision - some things are reading and modifying it, and you can't keep track of what order they are doing so.

[Take this advice on globals.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717045/should-i-use-global-variables/6717265#6717265)

Comment: Well, the problem is not GUIWindow.StandardBackgroundImage. This is in both cases not null. The problem really seems to be the Texture2D which is saved in StandardBackgroundImage.ImageStrip. In the first check it is not null, then in the Constructor it is null and after everything it is not null. It is only null in the Constructor. Because of the rest: Don't worry. Every Window has a Image Property, which holds the own image. The global StandardBackgroundImage is just to give the Window a standard image if it doesn't load any special image.

Comment: Okay, since the above was wrong and clearly you want to keep the global... Here's another idea: I believe ContentManager uses a separate thread. Perhaps the static `StandardBackgroundImage` hasn't yet been copied to that thread. If this is the case, you can remedy it with the [`volatile` keyword][2]. Give that a try and see if it's fixed.

Comment: It doesn't seem as it uses different threads. I used the volatile keyword and it threw the same error as before.             I don't want to keep the global, I would change that, if I could think about any other solution, but I honestly see no solution.

Comment: Well, if you've debugged and are convinced that the static variable isn't being seen by the constructor but is not null, you have a couple more options: you can create a new C# project and try to imitate this behavior. Basically make it as stripped-down as possible, for demonstration purposes, but to the point where it's doing the same thing. You will either discover your problem, or you'll have a test project to zip up and send to someone else to look at. Your other option is to dive into the XNA source code of the ContentManager class and its Load method and see what it's doing strangely.

Comment: Also let me know if you want me to migrate this to Stack Overflow, where you might get more answers.

Comment: Well I got the same problem in another class where i tried to use a image connected to the class in the same way. It seems as if the ContentManager holds the image local until the function where the iamge was loaded is done. I did a workaround to fix that. I knew what I have to do, but the actual question was why the Connten Manager behaves that way. So: Please migrate that to Stack Overflow, maybe there somebody can explain that behaviour.